# Default Value Based on a Label

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have created a report with a few different parameters in SSRS.

I have the available values for each parameter based off a corresponding dataset (which creates a drop-down).

If I have one parameter that has 10 different options as a drop down. How can I create the default value equal to specific options.

For example I have a report with the following fields:

Name - Age - Gender

I would like the default to be where Age IN (25, 30, 34). How can I go about this?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an easy thing to do.

Open the Properties dialog Age parameter while in design mode.

Go to the Default Values sheet, and choose the *Specify values* option. Then, in the Value section of that sheet, *Add* a value for each age that you want to use as a default; one value per line in the Value section.

For this to work as expected, you will have to check the *Allow multiple values* option on the General sheet of the same dialog. Choosing that turn a parameter into an `IN` parameter.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you so much! Something so simple was giving me a headache.